# How can I combine lines from two files using sed, awk, or other linux commands

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

I have two files:

file1.txt

> > apple
> >
> > orange
> >
> > banana

file2.txt

> > red
> >
> > white
> >
> > blue

What I would like to end up with is this:

file3.txt

> > apple
> >
> > red
> >
> > orange
> >
> > white
> >
> > banana
> >
> > blue

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 11):

You can use `paste`:

```
paste -d'\n' file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt
```

Comment: Ha that was short and sweet... +1 for that.  :)

Answer (score 4):

In `sed`,

```
sed 'R file2.txt' file1.txt > file3.txt
```

In `Bash`,

```
while IFS= read -r lineA && IFS= read -r lineB <&3 ; do echo "$lineA"; echo "$lineB"; done <file1.txt 3<file2.txt > file3.txt
```

Comment: To make the `bash` solution work in any POSIX shell, replace `read -u 3 -r lineB` with `read -r line B <&3` (but I agree, the `-u` is a little more readable when available).

Answer (score 2):

I am adding an awk solution:

```
awk '1;getline <"file2"' file1 >newfile
```

this one-liner works for your example.